# Chamar elementos de Layout (Menu) em arquivos separados

Tags: menu, flutter, dart

Bom dia galera!
Estou desenvolvendo um App no Flutter e já tenho várias telas desenvolvidas.
Gostaria de saber como posso criar um arquivo **.dart** com um **Bottom Navigation Menu** e chamar ele em todas as telas que já estão criadas.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Consegue, tudo em Flutter é widget, basta criar um Widget com esse seu componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá:

Você pode criar um arquivo chamado 'widgets' onde vai manter todos os widgets que serão usados em mais de uma tela. Exemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavigationMenu extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  height: 55.0,
  child: BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.grey[300],
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          iconSize: 30.0,
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          iconSize: 30.0,
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

E agora ir nas suas telas, e chamar pela classe 'BottomNavigationMenu()', Exemplo:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationMenu(),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Teste BottomNavigation',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

}

Lembrando do import da sua classe 'widgets'.

```
import 'package:flutter_testes/widgets.dart';
```

Comment: Cara é isso, funcionou perfeitamente.
Ajudou muito amigo, agradeço!

Estou começando agora no Flutter e estava quebrando a cabeça com algumas coisas rsrs. Mais uma vez obrigado!